# No sounds playing from USB external speaker on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, audio, audio-playback

I'm trying to get some sound to play via an external USB connected speaker from my Rasp Pi 3 Model B.

```
aplay -L
```

gives me this entry (along with many others)

```
default:CARD=Device
USB2.0 Device, USB Audio
Default Audio Device
```

So, I tried running:

```
aplay -D default:CARD=Device piano2.wav
```

But end up with the following

```
Playing WAVE 'piano2.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Stereo
aplay: pcm_write:2053: write error: Input/output error
```

I'm not even sure where to being to troubleshoot this. Thoughts on why this error is thrown?

More info. `aplay -l` gives me

```
   **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 0: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA]
  Subdevices: 7/7
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 1: bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI [bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 2: bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI1 [bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Device [USB2.0 Device], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Comment: Could be a permission problem. If you `aplay` the piano as root, does that work?

Comment: Tried running `sudo aplay -D sysdefault:CARD=Device piano2.wav` (I've moved around default devices to try to get this working). and I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Without digging down to the root cause (which I belive lies in ALSA configuration files `asound.conf` / `.asoundrc`), a practical solution to such problems is to install `pulseaudio` (along with its GUI configuration interface, `pavucontrol`) and set up the default audio sink there.

Answer (score 1):

If everything is going okay then you have to find these:

1. Did you set the output from audio menu which is at upper-right side of task bar?
2. Is your output forced or not from boot menu.

If you find these issues then solve then sequencially. Or check your USB card.

Comment: "upper-right side of task bar"? I'm only using the terminal as an interface at this point. And not clear on what you're asking in 2

Comment: @jonmrich forced output is defined in `raspi-config`